# Rails controller action returning 406 Not Acceptable instead of 404 Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-response-codes

Why does this not return 404 as expected when I pass in an object that doesn't exist? I can see that it gets into `scope_mosaic`, where it encounters a nil, but instead of returning 404 at that point, it carries on execution into the `social_share_image` method, where it returns a 406, and I get an `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error.

```
before_action :scope_mosaic

def social_share_image
  candidate_url = @mosaic.social_share_image
  if candidate_url.nil?
    redirect_to og_image_url
  else
    redirect_to candidate_url
  end
end

private

def scope_mosaic
  @mosaic = Mosaic.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if @mosaic.nil?
    render_error(:not_found, :not_found)
  end
end
```

**EDIT: `render_error`**

This is the `render_error` method, defined in `application_controller`:

```
def render_error(status, error_code, body = nil)
  data = { error_code: error_code }.merge(body || {})

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: data.to_json, status: status }
  end
end
```

Comment: Where is `render_error` coming from?

Comment: @DimitriJorge thanks, added!

Comment: It's a html request – which explains my problem! I wasn't returning in HTML format in `render_error`.

Comment: Try adding `format.html` in the `respond_to` block.